# Fetch only matching records from two entities

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Please help me with the MYSQL query.

Entity Name: OrderItem
Attributes: orderId(PK), orderItemSeqId(PK), productId

Entity Name: ProductFacility
Attributes: facilityId(PK), productId(PK), inventoryCount (Integer)

```
**OrderId  | orderItemSeqId | productId**

  OID1     |       0001     |   10000 

  OID1     |       0002     |   10001 

  OID1     |       0003     |   10002


**FacilityId | ProductId | InventoryCount**

  FC_1     |   10000    |    12

  FC_1     |   10001    |    5

  FC_1     |   10002    |    7

  FC_2     |   10001    |    1

  FC_2     |   10002    |    6

  FC_3     |   10002    |    7
```

Here I want to fetch the facility (FC_1) which has all the products available for order.

I don't want the facility records which has partial products (like facility FC_3 has only one (10002) product from order OID1)

I only want the facilityId records which have all the products from the order (ex OID1)

**IMPORTANT POINT:** This SQL will be executed on millions of records.

Comment: Hi @LalitDashora there are few answers to this queytion already. Did any of them helped you ? Comment if it did not... You can also give a vote up if the answer was of help to you...And you can accept the correct answer. If you do not know how to do this please ask . It would be nice from you to thank people that helped you with  your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * 
from ProductFacility  f1
where (select count(distinct InventoryCount) cnt_fac
       from ProductFacility  f2
       where f2.FacilityId = f1.FacilityId
       and InventoryCount > 0
       group by FacilityId ) = (select count(distinct productId) 
                                from OrderItem );
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=34c181b59218087a55169128977d9881)

Comment: This only works if there is only one order in `OrderT`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=91e7d75e561be930a963da87232b6982

Comment: Still doesn't work when there is more than one order in `OrderItem` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=575a6b1743bbcc87b42e1d9fcc594ee6

Comment: I've given you a demo with 2 orders - you can test your query there...

Comment: I did, it returns values. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=93392059be558ed92ce75c3ca8a4d24e Thanks!

Comment: @LalitDashora so does this work ? If not why ? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the facilities you are looking for

```
with cte as
(
 select OrderId, count(*)      as c
 from orderT a
 group by OrderId
)
select FacilityId, b.OrderId, count(*) as c from Facility a
inner join orderT b on a.ProductId  = b.ProductId
group by FacilityId, b.OrderId
having count(*) = (select c from cte c where c.OrderId = b.OrderId)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of which facilities can satisfy an order, you need to check which facility has `InventoryCount > 0` for each product in the order, which you can do with this query:

```
SELECT O.OrderId, F.FacilityID
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT productId
      FROM OrderItem) P
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT OrderId
            FROM OrderItem) O
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT FacilityId
            FROM ProductFacility) F
LEFT JOIN OrderItem OI ON OI.OrderId = O.OrderID AND OI.productId = P.productId
LEFT JOIN ProductFacility PF ON PF.FacilityId = F.FacilityId AND PF.productId = OI.productId AND PF.InventoryCount > 0
GROUP BY O.OrderId, F.FacilityID
HAVING COUNT(OI.ProductId) = COUNT(PF.ProductId)
```

I have added an additional order to my demo which requires products `10001` and `10002`; for that the output is

```
OrderId     FacilityID
OID1        FC_1
OID2        FC_1
OID2        FC_2
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93695f/35)

Comment: Just a note: on this fiddle in MySQL 8 and  MySQL 5.7 this has errors: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dfa20a9bc8e25576f5c648fefb6e2527

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select oc.orderId, ofc.facilityId
from
(
   select orderId, count(*) productCount
   from OrderItem
   group by orderId) oc 
inner join
(
   select pf.facilityId, oi.orderId, count(*) productsAvailableCount
   from ProductFacility pf
   inner join OrderItem oi on oi.productId = pf.productId and pf.inventoryCount > 0
   group by pf.facilityId, oi.orderId
) ofc on ofc.orderId = oc.orderId and oc.productCount = ofc.productsAvailableCount
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=006434cbfc6538482155fdb6e5053d79)**